# Is there a way, by which I can make two different connections in same application to same mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have an application in which I want to connect to same mongodb server but different databases, I'm using native-driver, and it throws an error. Is there better way to do it using native-driver.

Answer (score 0):

i suppose you can achieve it by making two instances of mongodbClient. and then connect with different databases.

```
var MongoClient1 = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var MongoClient2 = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
MongoClient1.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb1", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

  db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {});

});
MongoClient2.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb2", function(err, db) {
  if(err) { return console.dir(err); }

  db.collection('test', function(err, collection) {});

});
```